# Color of the bar behind the candlestick

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-visualization

How can I change the bar BEHIND the candlestick in Google Charts Api?

```
candlestick:{fallingColor:{fill:"red", strokeWidth:0.5,stroke:'black'},
              risingColor:{fill:"yellowgreen",strokeWidth:0.5,stroke:'black'}}}
```

`stroke` option changes the color of the box, but not the stick behind. I get this weird color combination of black box with green or red and a blue stic.
Cannot find it in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `colors` parameter will modify the color of the "stick". This specifies default colors for each series in the chart.

E.g. to change the stick to red for the first series and brown for the second series:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Mon', 20, 28, 38, 45],
      ['Tue', 31, 38, 55, 66],
      ['Wed', 50, 55, 77, 80],
      ['Thu', 77, 77, 66, 50],
      ['Fri', 68, 66, 22, 15]
      // Treat first row as data as well.
    ], true);

    var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        colors: ['red','brown'],
        candlestick: { 
              fallingColor:{ fill: "orange", strokeWidth:0.5, stroke:'black'},
              risingColor:{ fill: "yellowgreen", strokeWidth:0.5, stroke:'black'}
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.CandlestickChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/pdmpb9w1/2/).

Comment: Main problem I have is that if I have bar or line graph in it combo chart also, it overrides the colours. Any idea how to inherit colour but change the first one?

Comment: No - doesn't look like the Google API supports this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible but there's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/1014) about it if you want to chime in.